# World-Building Suggestion

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources

I started recently diving deep into World-Building and i'm looking for some guidance on how to start build foundations about World-Building. Is there something you suggest like books, movies etc?

Comment: this is going to depend  entirely on your goal and what aspect you are trying to build.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "best" way to start worldbuilding?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42696/is-there-a-best-way-to-start-worldbuilding)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of world you want to build. Books and movies like [The Lord of the Rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings) and [The Hobbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit) are great examples for medieval worlds in which magic is abundant. [Dungeons & Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons) also embraces similar scenarios a lot, with the plus that they are a natural world building experience, as the story isn't yet fully written and is usually made as you go through the expanding world.

Regarding a more science-esque world, the [Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars) and [Star Trek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek) series and [Starship Troopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers) are great to give some ideas on how the technology could develop and how military battles could go (with a bit of discretion though, as they usually focus a bit more on looking cool than on being accurate, not that I'm complaining ).

As for the world itself, James Cameron's [Avatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_(2009_film)) is one of my favorites regarding the creation of fauna and flora of your world. [Man after Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_After_Man) too is a classic of speculative evolution, so I recommend if you want some ideas of how your animals could potentially develop.

World building is a very diverse activity, ranging from ancient times to distant planets in far away futures. What traits make up your worlds and how much detail you give about certain traits about them is up to you. The best exercise is to just go ahead and try out a few concepts you like, and start developing from there. If you have issues with making your ideas work out, you can always ask here.

Welcome to Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: As far as tech-building, I would *strongly* recommend David Weber's [Honorverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorverse). It's not only fantastic space opera, the world-building is first-rate, with tech that is much more thought-out than average (certainly when compared against Star Wars, which is all over the place consistency-wise). For that matter, some of the companion books (I want to say [House of Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Steel:_The_Honorverse_Companion), in particular) actually get into some of Weber's world-building process.